# Rails: Given a String, check if an Array (of strings) contains a substring of String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Is there a more Railsy way to do this (without explicit regex, perhaps?):

```
array_o_strings = ["some strings", "I'd like", "to parse"]
string = "like to parse"
re = Regexp.union(array_o_strings.map { |i| Regexp.new(i) })
string =~ re
```

Just pining for magical Rails methods.

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing wrong with using a regular expression here if that's your intent. It's generally more efficient to use one of those than to go through the trouble of comparing arrays.

It's worth noting you don't have to do that much work to get this:

```
re = Regexp.union(array)
```

That should handle automatically escaping those strings and compiling them into a singular regular expression. Test with strings containing `*` and `?` to be sure.

One note to add on style is that the `=~` operator is a hold-over from Perl. It's preferable to use `string.match(re)` to make it clear what's going on there.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the array? It may be worth comparing the speed using a regex vs checking each element.  If the array is sorted shortest to longest that would help when checking one by one as you're more likely to find a match first.

In any event, this is one way:

```
array_o_strings.any?{|e| string.index(e) }
```